# Create a git diff of a file from SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

How to create a patch file from a **Source Tree**
Actually, i need to create a patch file of a specific modified file. i can view this using External diff or git diff filename in git bash.

Answer (score 19):

Assuming that this question is about the Git client SourceTree, here's how to create a patch file:

1. in the Log/History view, right-click on a commit
2. select the context menu option "Create Patch..."
3. in the "Create Patch" dialog window, select the commits to include in the patch, choose the location of your patch file on the filesystem, and click "Create Patch".

Answer (score 15):

In case you want to make a **Patch** from **not committed** changes (in other words from **Patch from Working Copy**):

1. Choose your **Uncommitted changes** line
   [image: List item]
2. Go to Actions
3. Create Patch

[image]

4. Choose the "Working Copy" Tab
5. Tick the check box to select all files
6. Click Create patch

Answer (score 6):

`git diff commitid1 commitid2 > patch.diff`